# Matlab -- Copy Structure Array without For Loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, copy, structure

I have a fairly simple question in Matlab. I want to copy n items of structure array (sumRT.P) to a matrix (m).  In C, I would just use a for loop, like this:

```
for i = 1:n    
    m(i) = sumRT(i).P;
end
```

But I bet there's a simpler way to copy an array in Matlab (that's the whole point of language right?). I tried this:

```
m = sumRT(1:n).P;
```

But this just copies the first item in sumRT.P to m, resulting in a 1 X 1 matrix.  Note, if I type, sumRT(2).P for example, I can see the second item.  Same for any number up to n.  Why is this wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the data types in your structure array. If they are types of variables, or if they are variables of the same size in arrays of different dimensions, then you can't put them into an array, but you can make them into a cell:

```
m={sumRT(1:n).P}
```

and cells are pretty simple to deal with, so this oughtn't be a big problem.

If they are all scalar numerical values, you can create a matrix:

```
m=cell2mat({sumRT(1:n).P})
```

Comment: Awesome! Using your example, this is the solution to my problem: m = cell2mat({sumRT(1:n).P});  I'm actually not totally clear on how certain structure arrays turn into cells.  It's causing some problems in my Matlab life.  Any advice?  I have a book on Matlab -- but it's not very comprehensive.  Is there a good Matlab "bible" out there (e.g., like Schildt's C handbook)?

Comment: Great! I did get the notation mixed up in my answer, looks like you worked it out anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
m = squeeze(cell2mat(struct2cell(sumRT(1:n))));
```

This converts the struct array to a cell array, and then to a (numeric) array, and then squeezes it by remoiving singleton dimensions.

Example:

```
>> sumRT(1).P = 10; sumRT(2).P = 20; sumRT(3).P = 30;
>> n = 2; %// copy first two elements only
>> m = squeeze(cell2mat(struct2cell(sumRT(1:n))))
m =
    10
    20
```

Comment: I get the following error for this code:
     Error using cell2mat (line 45)
     All contents of the input cell array must be of the same data type.

Comment: So, I tried to edit your code to:  m4 = squeeze(cell2mat(struct2cell(sumRT(1:n).P)))

  And I got this error message.
Undefined function 'struct2cell' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Comment: You haven't told us what the contents of `sumRT(1).P`, `sumRT(2).P` are in your case. I assumed they are numbers; and in that case my code does work (see my example)

Comment: I can see that your code works for your data.  But it's not working for mine.  The contents are doubles.

Comment: Since you said that `m = sumRT(1:n).P;` resulted in a 1x1 matrix, I had to assume the field contents were scalars. Next time, please specify your question with all necessary details